# Build fails when installing asdf Python plugin

Tags: python, macos, asdf

I've spent hours on this. Can't figure out why I'm not able to install the `asdf` Python plugin.

Whenever I run `asdf install python` I get this error:

```
python-build 3.8.10 /Users/danielrvt/.asdf/installs/python/3.8.10
python-build: use openssl@1.1 from homebrew
python-build: use readline from homebrew
Downloading Python-3.8.10.tar.xz...
-> https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.8.10/Python-3.8.10.tar.xz
Installing Python-3.8.10...
python-build: use tcl-tk from homebrew
python-build: use readline from homebrew
python-build: use zlib from xcode sdk

BUILD FAILED (OS X 12.3.1 using python-build 2.2.5-13-g6d20b3b1)

Inspect or clean up the working tree at /var/folders/2m/x55h424x6316mw17vv1zky7c0000gn/T/python-build.20220420163159.19178
Results logged to /var/folders/2m/x55h424x6316mw17vv1zky7c0000gn/T/python-build.20220420163159.19178.log

Last 10 log lines:
checking for --with-cxx-main=<compiler>... no
checking for clang++... no
configure:

  By default, distutils will build C++ extension modules with "clang++".
  If this is not intended, then set CXX on the configure command line.
  
checking for the platform triplet based on compiler characteristics... darwin
configure: error: internal configure error for the platform triplet, please file a bug report
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

Not sure what I'm doing wrong here...

Comment: It looks like it wants the `clang++` compiler installed in order to build some C++ code. Install clang and try again.

Comment: I already installed gcc using brew. Still no luck

Comment: Check the mentioned log file for more details.